# WordPress shows <codes> after migration

Tags: custom-post-types, migration, localhost

I copied the files of our WordPress live site from Cpanel and export the database. In my local, I paste the WordPress files to htdocs > devfolder and then import the database to localhost/PHPMyAdmin. Using search and replace the live URL to localhost. Also, changed the configuration of the wp-config file. Then when I visit my local version, the site has some code on the upper part of the front end and admin when you logged in. I think that is the code for FAQ custom post type because that is missing compared to the live site.

How can I fix that kind of error?
Thanks.

Comment: Show us the `code` that you see.

Comment: Thank you for responding. The code is too long but here are some of  the code:
_x( 'FAQ', 'post type general name' ), 'singular_name' => _x( 'FAQ', 'post type singular name' ), 'add_new' => _x( 'Add New', 'FAQ' ), 'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New FAQ' ), 'edit_item' => __( 'Edit FAQ' ), 'new_item' => __( 'New FAQ' ), 'all_items' => __( 'All FAQ' ), 'view_item' => __( 'View FAQs' ), 'search_items' => __( 'Search FAQs' ), 'not_found' => __( 'No FAQs found' ), 'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No FAQs found in the Trash' ), 'parent_item_colon' => '', 'menu_name' => 'FAQs' ) // // CPT BRANDS ON BOARD

Comment: Find the code or plugin that creates the FAQ cpt and check it for errors - it is something basic but only a person with admin access to your site can find the exact cause.

Comment: @shanebp thanks. Sorry I'm a bit newbie here.The codes have been gone. It's weird that every open php tag there is no "php", just "<?", so I tried to add "php" on every open tag. Now, the other thing is the styling. Styles are all broken but the stylesheet is pointing to the css file.

Comment: Try loading the css url directly and see if it loads. And you should be using enqueue. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/